# Compare with unmodified feature in VS2022

Tags: settings, visual-studio-2022

From one day to another the double click feature in VS2022 was disbled, but I don't retrieve that setting anywhere.
How I can return  the "compare with unmodified" feature in Git Changes usable with a double click?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on **...** in **Git Changes** tab to the right of "Changes" word and choose **"Compare File as Default Action"**.

[image]